# How to get the limsup / liminf value of a mathematical function in python?

Tags: python, math, sympy

For example, see the mathematica code below.

```
In[1]:= Max[Limit[Sin[x], x -> Infinity]]
Out[1]:= 1
In[2]:= Min[Limit[Sin[x], x -> Infinity]]
Out[2]:= -1
```

I want to do something like this in python(maybe Sympy).
Using sympy, evaluating `limit(sin(x), x, oo)` returns `sin(oo)`, and it's not range or something.
So I'm confused how to get the upper/lower limit of it.
I think it's not so hard problem but I can find seldom information on that.
Can I do that in python?

---

Edit(2015/11/21)

I did some tries on the way @Teepeemm suggested, and still made no fruit.
This is the Try&error's product:

```
import sympy as sym
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

sym.init_printing()

x,y,z,l,u = sym.symbols('x y z l u')

f = sym.simplify(sym.sin(x) * sym.exp(-x))

df = sym.diff(f,x)
numeric_df = sym.lambdify(x, df)
numeric_sup_l_u = differential_evolution(numeric_df, [(l,u)])
sup_l_u = sym.sympify(numeric_sup_l_u["x"])
sup_l = sym.limit(sup_l_u, u, sym.oo)
print sym.simplify(sym.limit(sup_l, l, sym.oo))
```

The two problems on the way:

- Using scipy functions require to `lambdify` expressions, but once I `lambdify` expressions, I cannot `sympify` valuables again.
- I don't know how to give `diferential_evolution` to the range including sympy's valuable or `+oo`.

Comment: I don't know sympy or Mathematica well enough, but the usual way to define limsup is `Limit[Max]` (otherwise, it'd be suplim).  Is that doable in sympy?

Comment: Thank you for comment, and yes you are right and maybe to the point. With scipy, I might be able to calculate `sup(f(x)), x>k` for any `k`.  If so simply do `k -> +oo` with sympy... I will try it after downloading entire newest scipy package.